# Creating a Typekit search functionality with EE and Solspace Super Search

Tags: ee2, ajax, search, supersearch

Typekit has a nice dynamic search feature on their site which i would like to try and include in a project i am working on, [www.typekit.com/fonts](http://www.typekit.com/fonts).

I don't mean the search box with the auto suggest, i am referring to the sidebar on the right

I have used Super Search by Solspace before and thought it would be a suitable add-on to use.

I am going to have 2 groups that i need to search / filter by, these are 'Country' and 'Sector'
So it would be like Typekit have it, just with 2 filter sections

If anyone could shed any light on how this would work and/or how i may go about this, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial might get you started http://blog.aaronmbushnell.com/post/23434803999/creating-an-ajax-filter-using-solspace-super-search

If it's just 2 groups you might also consider using dynamic parameters: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/dynamic_parameters.html